# verify auth in python mock_requests lib

Tags: python, unit-testing, requests-mock

I'm creating a unit test making sure my http client is passing auth token correctly. I'm using **requests_mock** lib

```
with requests_mock.mock() as m:
    m.get(
        "https://my-endpoint",
        text="{}",
    )
history = m.request_history[0]
assert "Bearer test" == history._request.headers.get("Authorization")
```

But history._request is a protected member so I'd like to avoid binding to protected members in my code. Is there some more proper way to check Authorization header in **requests_mock** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using `history._request.headers`, you can use `history.headers`.

For example:

```py
import requests
import requests_mock

with requests_mock.mock() as m:
    m.get(
        "https://my-endpoint",
        text="{}",
    )

    headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer test'}
    requests.get('https://my-endpoint', headers=headers)
    history = m.request_history[0]
    assert "Bearer test" == history.headers.get("Authorization")
```